# identify and insert the missing rows

Tags: perl

An array is populated from a tab delimited text (5 column) file that sometimes is missing rows. I need to identify and insert the missing rows. Inserting a string "blank row found" is sufficient.

Here is an example of data from file:

```
chr1:11174372   MTOR    42939   42939   7
chr1:65310459   JAK1    1948    1948    3
```

I’ve created an array of elements that identifies the second column of each row that should be present in the file, in the order each row should be present. However, I'm not sure how to continue from here, since I'm unable to install any Perl modules on the server (e.g. Arrays::Utils).

Is comparing arrays the correct way of approaching this problem?  Perhaps there is a straightforward solution, that doesn’t require installation of any CPAN modules? Thanks for your help.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
#use Arrays::Utils;

opendir my $dir, "/data/test_all_runs" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @run_folder = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;

my $run_folder = pop @run_folder; print "The folder is".$run_folder."\n";

my $home="/data/";                                                     

my $CNV_file = $home."test_all_runs/".$run_folder."/CNV.txt";

my @CNVarray;
open(TXT2, "$CNV_file");
        while (<TXT2>){
            push (@CNVarray, $_);   
            }
    close(TXT2);

foreach (@CNVarray){
    chop($_);
}

my @array1 = map { $_->[1] } @CNVarray;

my @array2 = qw(MTOR JAK1 NRAS DDR2 MYCN ALK IDH1 ERBB4 RAF1 CTNNB1 PIK3CA DCUN1D1 FGFR3 PDGFRA KIT APC FGFR4 ROS1 ESR1 EGFR CDK6 MET SMO BRAF FGFR1 MYC JAK2 GNAQ RET FGFR2 HRAS CCND1 BIRC2 KRAS ERBB3 CDK4 AKT1 MAP2K1 IDH2 NF1 ERBB2 BRCA1 GNA11 MAP2K2 JAK3 AR MED12);

    my %array1_hash;
    my %array2_hash;

    # Create a hash entry for each element in @array1
    for my $element ( @array1 ) {
       $array1_hash{$element} = @array1;
    }

    # Same for @array2: This time, use map instead of a loop
    map { $array_2{$_} = 1 } @array2;

    for my $entry ( @array2 ) {

            if ( not $array1_hash{$entry} ) {
                return 1;  #Entry in @array2 but not @array1: Differ

        }else {
           return 0;   #Arrays contain the same elements
        }
    #if ( keys %array_hash1 != keys %array_hash2 ) {
       #return 1;   #Arrays differ
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**    The best version is reached at the end.  It is a few lines of code.

---

If I get it right, you have a separate reference list of key-words that need to be in the second field in a row, with rows in that order.  One way to find skipped rows is to iterate through both lists.

That approach can be picky and error prone but here it can be made easier by removing the front element from the reference list each time. Then you always need to compare the current line against the first element in the reference list. Here is the basic logic, with the better version further below.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $cnv_fh, '<', $CNV_file or die "Can't open $CNV_file: $!";
my @CNVarray = <$cnv_fh>;
close $cnv_fh;
# chomp(@CNVarray);

my @ref_list = qw(MTOR JAK1 ...);

foreach my $line (@CNVarray) 
{
    if ( (split /\t/, $line)[1] eq $ref_list[0] ) {  # good row
        shift @ref_list;
        print $line, "\n";
    }
    else {
        shift @ref_list;
        print "blank row found\n";
        while ( (split /\t/, $line)[1] ne $ref_list[0] ) {
            # multiple missing rows? keep going through the reference list
            shift @ref_list;
            print "blank row found\n";
    }
 }
 # We are done with the array, but are there more reference items?
 print "blank row found\n" for @ref_list;
```

The `while` loop is needed since multiple rows can be missing (in a row), so we need to get to the place in the reference list that does match the current row. A few notes on the code.

- The filehandle read `<...>` in the list context returns a list with all lines from the resource.
- The [`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) in the original code removes the last *character*, probably not what you want. It is the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) that removes the new line (or really `$/`).

Tested against the reference list `qw(AA BB CC DD EE)` with the input file (note spaces not tabs)

```
1 AA first
2 BB more
5 EE last
```

To test with this, change `/\t/` to `/\s/` (what will then work for tabs as well).  It prints

```
1 AA first
2 BB more
blank row found
blank row found
5 EE last
```

With further elements added to the `@ref_list` (`FF` etc) further `blank ...` lines are printed.

---

The code above can be simplified.  Lines are also collected in an array, then printed to a new file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $cnv_fh, '<', $CNV_file or die "Can't open $CNV_file: $!";
my @CNVarray = <$cnv_fh>;
close $cnv_fh;
chomp(@CNVarray);

my @ref_list = qw(MTOR JAK1 ...);
my @new_lines;

foreach my $line (@CNVarray) 
{
    while ( (split /\t/, $line)[1] ne $ref_list[0] ) {
        shift @ref_list;
        push @new_lines, 'blank row found';
        print "blank row found\n";
    }
    shift @ref_list;
    push @new_lines, $line;         
    print $line, "\n";
}
# There may be more items remaining on the reference list
for (@ref_list) {
    push @new_lines, 'blank row found';
    print "blank row found\n" 
}


my $filled_file = 'skipped_rows_added.txt';
open my $out_fh, '>', $filled_file  or die "Can't open $filled_file: $!";
print $out_fh "$_\n" for @new_lines;
close $out_fh;
```

This behaves the same way with the test input above. It can be simplified further yet

```
foreach my $line (@CNVarray) 
{
    while ( (split /\t/, $line)[1] ne shift @ref_list ) {
        print "blank row found\n";
    }
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

The [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) returns the removed element, which is what need be tested against.

---

A note on [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) syntax, following the code update (`"\t"` changed to `/\t/`).

When invoked as `split /$patt/, $str`, the `$patt` is used as a *regular expression*, with a few very minor differences.  So with `/\s/` the string is split on white space as understood in regex, thus including the tab, for example.

With double quotes `"..."` used instead of `/.../`, what is inside is interpolated first which may result in surprises, in particular with escapes. (Unless it is used as `m"..."` in which case it is merely a regex with `"` being the delimiter.)

In the above code for the tab one can use `/\t/`, or `"\t"`, or `'\t'` (or `/\s/` which includes yet other types of space).  The `"\t"` was changed to `/\t/`, which is better in my opinion, being clearer (it *is* a regex, no questions asked). Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for the early edit and for the comment.

Comment: @user3781528  I've edited the original answer considerably (also removing a bug in an edge case)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Thank you, your code works great. if I wanted to write all of the lines back to a new array, including the "blank row found" lines. do I push each line into a new array at the end of the foreach loop?

Comment: @user3781528  Yes, it is probably simplest to `push`.  Wherever it does a `print` replace with `push`.

Comment: It would push lines back into the same array? interesting, thank you.

Comment: @user3781528  Please note that my test case uses spaces in fact

Comment: @user No, I meant what your comment said -- make a new array.  I meant to say that you do that where the `print`s are. So where it says `print "blank ..."` you'd say `push @new_file, 'blank ...';` and where it goes `print $line` you say `push @new_file, $line;`.  (You _could_ manipulate the original array, too.)

Comment: @user3781528  I added that to the answer. Also, I now see that I didn't address the comment above properly (?) so you may have not seen it!

Comment: I saw the comment and was able to implement the changes. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you for the early edit, fixing the `split` pattern

Comment: @zdim: You're welcome. I always prefer slashes `/\t/` for split as in truth it is a regex pattern.

Comment: @Borodin I do use `''` sometimes, to distinguish from regex, provide a clue that it isn't ... which got me in trouble here.  Should probably abandon that.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this

The input file is read into a hash, keyed by the value of the second column. Then the hash is read back and printed in the specified sequence of keys

Most of the code is finding the input file and setting up the sequence of keys. The core of the program is only three lines of code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

my $home = '/data';

my @run_folder = grep -f, glob catfile($home, 'test_all_runs', '*', 'CNV.txt');
die "No CNV file found" unless @run_folder;

my $cnv_file = $run_folder[-1];
print "The file is $cnv_file\n\n";

my @sequence = qw/
    MTOR    JAK1    NRAS    DDR2    MYCN    ALK
    IDH1    ERBB4   RAF1    CTNNB1  PIK3CA  DCUN1D1
    FGFR3   PDGFRA  KIT     APC     FGFR4   ROS1
    ESR1    EGFR    CDK6    MET     SMO     BRAF
    FGFR1   MYC     JAK2    GNAQ    RET     FGFR2
    HRAS    CCND1   BIRC2   KRAS    ERBB3   CDK4
    AKT1    MAP2K1  IDH2    NF1     ERBB2   BRCA1
    GNA11   MAP2K2  JAK3    AR      MED12
/;

open my $fh, '<', $cnv_file or die qq{Unable to open "$cnv_file" for input: $!};

my %data;
$data{ (split)[1] } = $_ while <$fh>;

print $data{$_} // "no data for $_\n" for @sequence;
```

#### output

```
The file is /data/test_all_runs/XXX/CNV.txt

chr1:11174372   MTOR    42939   42939   7
chr1:65310459   JAK1    1948    1948    3
no data for NRAS
no data for DDR2
no data for MYCN
no data for ALK
no data for IDH1
no data for ERBB4
no data for RAF1
no data for CTNNB1
no data for PIK3CA
no data for DCUN1D1
no data for FGFR3
no data for PDGFRA
no data for KIT
no data for APC
no data for FGFR4
no data for ROS1
no data for ESR1
no data for EGFR
no data for CDK6
no data for MET
no data for SMO
no data for BRAF
no data for FGFR1
no data for MYC
no data for JAK2
no data for GNAQ
no data for RET
no data for FGFR2
no data for HRAS
no data for CCND1
no data for BIRC2
no data for KRAS
no data for ERBB3
no data for CDK4
no data for AKT1
no data for MAP2K1
no data for IDH2
no data for NF1
no data for ERBB2
no data for BRCA1
no data for GNA11
no data for MAP2K2
no data for JAK3
no data for AR
no data for MED12
```